# Display div on click

Tags: jquery, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
$("#divId").hide();


$("#div1").click(function (event) {
    $("#divId").show().css({
        position: "absolute",
     top:event.pageY, left: event.pageX
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"style="height:150px;width:150px;border:1px solid blue;"></div>


<div id="divId" style="height:20px;width:20px; border:1px solid red;">  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This program is not working. Does it require any google api? Please help. I want to create something like this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/aFACA/32/

Comment: Your jsfiddle working fine , so what is ur problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You need to include jQuery library:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

as well as wrapping your code inside **[DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)** handler `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or shorter form `$(function() {...});` to make sure all of your DOM elements have been loaded properly before executing your jQuery code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#divId").hide();
    $("#div1").click(function (event) {
        $("#divId").show().css({
            position: "absolute",
            top: event.pageY,
            left: event.pageX
        });
    });
});
```

Remember to put above script after including jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the jquery file. You can download it or use google. Please check below:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
```

And also it needs to be wrap on $(document).ready

Please check this link: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 0):

place your script before 
 or place scripts in $(document).ready(function{... your code ...});

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to access the DOM while the DOM is not ready. Wrap your code so it'll be executed when the DOM is ready:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#divId").hide();


        $("#div1").click(function (event) {
            $("#divId").show().css({
                position: "absolute",
                top: event.pageY, left: event.pageX
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angularJs. It has ng-hide and ng-show directives.This will make your this code of just 3,4 lines

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow
Check this out. If you have any problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Place the content in this div

```
<div id="hide">PUT CONTENT YOU WANT TO HIDE HERE</div>
```

Then use this url to hide the content which is inside the div

```
<a href="#" onClick="toggle_visibility('hide');">Hide this box for printing!</a>
```

Finally place this in the same file as your div

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```